# How to access specific data values from tooltip - Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to pass array of objects as data to graph data, including the value for x and some other values to be used in each tooltip.

In my data array, each object contains values for `x` and `value` variables. I want to access this `value` inside `tooltips` and finally to display the value inside the tooltip that appears when mouse hover on each graph data.

Here is my code:

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['2017/06/12', '2017/06/23', '2017/07/12', '2017/07/23', '2017/08/12', '2017/08/23', '2017/09/12'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Values',
      data: [{
          y: 12,
          value: 12
        },
        {
          y: 3,
          value: 13
        },
        {
          y: 1,
          value: 15
        },
        {
          y: -3,
          value: 5
        },
        {
          y: 67,
          value: 18
        },
        {
          y: 12,
          value: 11
        },
        {
          y: 13,
          value: 19
        }
      ],
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 2
    }]
  },
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      // HERE I WANT TO ACCESS VALUE VARIABLE AND DISPLAY IT IN TOOLTIP
    },
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Chart.js Tooltip docs have a [section on Label Callback](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#label-callback) which shows how you can specify the text that displays for a given data point. You need to write a function that is supplied with the following parameters:

```
tooltips: {
  callbacks: {
    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
      return '...';
    }
  }
}
```

The section for [Tooltip Item Interface](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-item-interface) shows you what information is passed to the callback via `tooltipItem`. The important ones here are `datasetIndex` (index of the dataset the item comes from) and `index` (index of this data item in the dataset). Using these you can access the correct item within `data`.

Putting that together here is a very simple example accessing `y` and `value` in the tooltip

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sheilak/2pgqcks6/) (with `backgroundColor`/`borderColor` removed as it's causing an error):

```
tooltips: {
  callbacks: {
    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
      var item = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
      return item.y  + ' ' + item.value;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks! that does what I want. However, tooltips appears only when single values for borderColor and backgroundColor is given, but that's a considerable problem.

Comment: I don't know if that will work for a line chart. See issue with workaround here: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2430

Comment: Unfortunately, the `data` parameter is no longer available in ChartJS 4.x.x. As noted in [the 3.x Migration Guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/migration/v3-migration.html): "The callbacks no longer are given a data parameter. The tooltip item parameter contains the chart and dataset instead."